# Create and define an Array of NSButtons for OSX

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, nsbutton

trying to create a variable number of NSButtons in OSX in ViewController. Tried doing this by defining an Array of NSButtons. 
On running I am getting a fatal error: Array index out of range (lldb).
Being partially competent in Swift and somewhat dyslexic, would appreciate any help. Have tried to look at past answers, but could not find anything helpful.

```
var arrayOfButton: [NSButton] = []
    for counter in 0...3 {
        var tempButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 160 * counter, y: 40 * counter , width: 150, height: 30))
        print("created tempButton")
        arrayOfButton[counter] = tempButton
        arrayOfButton[counter].title = "Button \(counter)"
        self.view.addSubview(arrayOfButton[counter])
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending to the array;

```
  arrayOfButton.append(tempButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 0 buttons in your array, but you're calling the indexes of counter to an empty array, causing an index error. Try adding the temp button by

`arrayOfButtons.apend(temp)`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create an array of buttons and then define it to be empty.

```
var arrayOfButton: [NSButton] = []
```

Then you enter a loop and try to address the first element of your array:

```
arrayOfButton[counter] = tempButton
```

But your array is empty.  It doesn't have a first element.  It doesn't have any elements.  You have not put anything into the array.  Array element 0 is out of bounds for the array because there is no element 0.

To put your temp button into the array, you need to append it onto the end of your array:

```
// Use append to put the temp button into the array
arrayOfButton.append(tempButton)
```

Comment: Thank you user2277872, @dreamriver, and John. That was stupid of me!

Comment: `func buttonPressed (button: NSButton?)  {
            button!.title = "pressed"
        }` When I press the buttons, the action does not get executed. If I make a manual fucntion call, it does.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayOfButton[counter] = tempButton`.

This is an empty array. Trying to assign into it's zeroth element doesn't make any sense. Try `.append` to fill out your array.